# python schedule library to stop previously running thread when new scheduled thread starts

Tags: python, multithreading, scheduling

I have a same thread running every 10 min. but when the new thread starts i want to quit the previous thread so it doesn't keep adding up the space. how can i achieve that. for scheduling of thread.I'm using python schedule library.

this is how I'm scheduling right now

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(sts,threadFunc)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to this question:

- identify the currently running job, which is fairly easy.
- Kill a running thread in python. There's no great solution for this, and the following code implements the 'stop flag' approach.

I'm solving the first challenge by using a global variable. This variable, named `running_thread`, holds the currently running thread so that a new job can kill it if needed.

The second challenge requires the running thread to constantly check the status of some flag ('the stop flag'). If the stop flag is set on that thread, it immediately exists.

Here's a code skeleton that demonstrates both these ideas. Jobs take a random amount of time, and I've scheduled them to start every 1 second.

```
import threading
import time
import schedule
import random 

running_thread = None

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

def job():
    current_thread = threading.currentThread()
    sleep_time = random.random() * 5

    
    print(f"Starting job, about to sleep {sleep_time} seconds, thread id is {current_thread.ident}")
    counter = 0 
    while counter < sleep_time:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        counter += 0.1
        if current_thread.stopped():
            print ("Stopping job")
            break
    print(f"job with thread id {current_thread.ident} done")

def threadFunc(): 
    global running_thread
    if running_thread: 
        print("Trying to stop thread")
        running_thread.stop()
    print("Strting thread")
    running_thread = StoppableThread(target = job)
    running_thread.start()

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(threadFunc)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(.5)
```